# OM how to add class to html element

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

Trying out OM, ReactJS and ClojureScript. I am trying to add a classname to my `dom` element. Ideally I want something like this:

```
<div>
    <i class="icon-alert">Contact list</i>
</div>
```

right now: It writes like:

```
<div>
    <i>Contact list</i>
</div>
```

---

This is my core.clj

```
(defn new-view [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [this]
      (dom/i #js {:class "icon-alert"} "Contacts list")
               )))


(om/root new-view app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "row1"))})
```

This is the relevant part from my index.html

```
<div id="row1">
      <h2>Figwheel template</h2>
      <p>Checkout your developer console.</p>
</div>
```

---

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing around with my code, make me realise: I was writing `class` instead of `className`. Feel so dumb. It works now. I will let it here so people with the same issues can get the help they need.

```
(defn new-view [data owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render [this]
      (dom/i #js {:className "icon-alert"} "Contacts list")
               )))
```